# Is JNDI Lookup Possible with Java Web Start?

Tags: java, glassfish-3, jndi, java-web-start, jnlp

Hi Everyone,

I am Learning about Java Web Start Application to Launching Application and i successfully created and tested sample Application which is been Launched by JW(Java Webstart). But the Problem is I just want Someone to clarify whether JNDI lookup for EJB Method from Stand Alone Application using JW is Possible? I have been trying to Lookup an EJB Method for last two days.but I Keep failing in it. And my JNLP File is as Follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.1.2:8080/JNDIJEE-war/" href="JNDIAppClient.jnlp">
<information>
<title>JNDI Test</title>
<vendor>Ixplore</vendor>
<homepage href="http://192.168.1.2:8080/JNDIJEE-war/" />
<description>Testing Testing</description>
<offline-allowed/> 
<association mime-type="application/x-java-jnlp-file"  extensions="jnlp"/> 
<shortcut online="true">
<desktop/>
<menu submenu="My Corporation Apps"/>
</shortcut>
</information>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.6+" />
<jar href="JNDIAppClient.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/appserv-rt.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/gf-client.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javaee.jar"/>    
<jar href="javaee-api-6.0.jar"/>
<jar href="JNDIRemote.jar"/>
<property name="org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost" value="192.168.1.2:8080"/>
<property name="org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort" value="3700"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="TestClient"/>
</jnlp>
```

I have signed all the jar file using keytool.Once i run JNLP file its been launched with Unexpected Error:Null Pointer Exception saying,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestClient.<init>(TestClient.java:30)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my lookup Code for your reference,

```
                    Properties props1;
                    InitialContext context;
                    props1 = new Properties();
                    props1.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
                    props1.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.2");
                    props1.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
                    context = new InitialContext(props1);
                    remote = (JavaWebstartSessionRemote)context.lookup("java:global/JNDIJEE/JNDIJEE-ejb/JavaWebstartSession");
```

i am using glassfish 3.1 application Server and Java 7.Kindly help me if you could.

Comment: Well then make your problem domain easier: skip the webstart part and create a very basic command line Java application which performs the lookup of the EJB. If it doesn't work there either, the problem is with the lookup of the bean and you can't pin anything on Java Web Start being involved.

Comment: @Gimby:thanks for the reply i tried the application with command line and also using Netbeans IDE too.Application working fine.but it doesnt seems to be working with webstart

Comment: I would expect JNDI lookups to be supported. Double-check your application against the [deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7693/beaem/index.html).

Comment: There's no reason why a JWS program wouldn't support JNDI. Much more likely that you just haven't done it right.

Comment: i couldnt find the mistake. i just tried the same application with weblogic and surprisngly it works fine.but i dont find the reason why it doesnt works with glassfish.Is there any other glassfish jar files do i have add?plz help me if u know anything about it.

Comment: JNDI is definitely supported from WebStart - we have several webstart clients that all make JNDI calls to get remote EJB interfaces. I would bet there's some type of issue with the context lookup.  We use JBoss and there are usually 2 things that need to be setup, the initial context factory AND an provider_url, which I don't see in your code snippet.  Double check that lookup.